# What strategies work best to get to Level 100 of Skull Cavern?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm in Summer, Year 3 of Stardew Valley and still haven't made it to Level 100 of the Skull Cavern. I have attempted the quest about three times. Each time I have:

- brought plenty of food
- brought a stockpile of staircases and Mega Bombs
- waited till the fortune for the day was of high luck

I am wondering if it is the best strategy to go when the day is of highest luck? *("The spirits are very happy today! They will do their best to shower everyone with good fortune.")*
Last time I went, I was doing well but ran out of time in the day (wasn't getting enough shoots down multiple floors).

What's the best recipe for success?

Comment: If the goal is **just to reach** Level 100, I recall one of the suggestions on a YT vid was to place the staircase as soon as you enter each level until you reach 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I descend the Skull Cavern quickly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297850/how-do-i-descend-the-skull-cave-quickly)

Comment: Good point @agarza

Comment: @TimmyJim - Missed that, sorry! I guess my question still stands in the sense that I don't necessarily want to drain so many resources on staircases alone. But that may be just the best strategy, which I'm willing to accept.

Comment: @hopejotet my understanding is that these are the only real ways to get that low in the Cavern fast.  When I asked that question 5 years ago, I remember thinking the same thing.  I accepted the fact that these were the only real options, and I even remember **not** even trying to attempt them because I wasn't going to get that much stone to get all the staircases.  I ended up just getting the Iridium over time using other methods.

Comment: You can use Jade and Crystalariums (each will produce new jade every day and 16 hours in-game), then trade the Jade on Sundays with the desert trader for stairs. This bypasses needing massive amounts of stone to make 100 staircases, and if you still have other goals to achieve, shouldn't hold up your gameplay too much timewise either.

Comment: Oooooo love that tip, thank you!! @Tinkeringbell

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.